# RSS Tolerance calculation and usage

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, tolerance

From my experience, I've been calculating RSS tolerances by squaring all relevant tolerances, summing them up and then square rooting the sums... ie: **RSS=[Σ(tol^2)]^0.5**

I've also heard of other methods to calculate RSS including dividing by 3, ie: **RSS=3*[Σ(tol/3^2)]^0.5**

What is the main difference between these two methods?

Comment: Divide **and** multiply by 3....